# RAID Mirroring Without data loss

Tags: raid, raid1

How can one save data from being lost while configuring RAID 1 mirroring on X 3550 M5 lenovo/IBM server having M1215 RAID controller?

Comment: What makes you think data will be lost when you set up RAID 1?

Comment: When you try to set-up RAID, it warns you the disk data will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

The only guarantee that you won't lose data is up-to-date, tested backups taken before you start work.

The raid controller you're talking about might well have its own mechanism for 'safely' converting a populated jbod disk to a raid member whose content is then replicated to a new disk in the new array but I bet it will extol the virtues of backups before starting.

Comment: The problem is M1215 RAID controller doesn't have any resources available online which could confirm if the RAID controller has that mechanism. I couldn't find that mechanism when I tried the RAID configuration. Doing any changes to the RAID configuration would erase whole data. Can't take risk with the data.

Comment: Which kinda brings us back to 'take backup, do drive install, restore backup if necessary', doesn't it?

Comment: Of course it does!! That's a basic. Isn't it?